# Slack API re-activate user after deactivating by users.admin.setInactive

Tags: slack, slack-api

When a user was deactivated (after using undocumented API method  [`users.admin.setInactive`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.setInactive.md)), is there any possibilities to re-activate him using slackAPI? Unfortunatelly i didn't find any method for this...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found is by using Slack SIM API. See PATCH /Users/{id} on:
https://api.slack.com/scim

Worth mentioning this is only available to Slack workspaces on the Plus plan and Slack Enterprise Grid.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

After long searching it is possible to get users reactivated with the free api. You can not do it with a legacy key and api key. But you can with an session api key

see https://github.com/SvenHamers/slack-sessiontoken for an example how to automate it (Golang)

Api: users.admin.setRegular